# How to use ensym as a variable to store values within function

Tags: r, rlang

How can I use `ensym` or another appropriate function that will store this as a variable and assign a value to it.

For example:

```
quest <- 'a'
list(rlang::ensym(quest) = 1)
>Error: unexpected '=' in "list(rlang::ensym(quest)="
```

Expected output:

```
$a
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 3):

fully rlang approach might be

```
library(rlang)
quest <- 'a'
list2(!!(quest) := 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `dplyr::lst`

```
dplyr::lst(!! quest := 1)
$a
[1] 1
```

---

Or in `base R`, use `setNames`

```
setNames(list(1), quest)
$a
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way:

1. Create an empty list `lst`.
2. Use  `[[` to add a new element to the list with the name specified by `quest` variable and assign the value 1 to it:

```
quest <- 'a'
lst <- list()
lst[[quest]] <- 1
lst

$a
[1] 1
```